# How to upload binaries to Azure pipeline and get signed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

All

I have an Azure pipeline which can sign binary files(like *.exe file with digital signature). Now the process goes like this:

1. I add the binaries to GitHub repository from my laptop and commit.
2. I manually trigger the pipeline.
3. Pipeline pull the binaries from github to workspace and sign them.

Is there any easier way(for example: a pipeline task) to upload the binaries directly into the pipeline workspace? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a [**Microsoft-hosted agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run the pipeline, each time you run the pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine for each job in the pipeline.

So you must download the binary files to the agent machine every time, no matter where you download these files from. At this time, putting these binary files in the source repository of the pipeline should be the easiest way to download them to the working directory of the pipeline every time. Because each time you run the pipeline, by default the pipeline will automatically download the source repository to the pipeline working directory, so the binary files stored in the source repository also will be downloaded together.

If you are using a [**self-hosted agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) run the pipeline, you can store these binary files under a fixed directory that is outside the pipeline working directory on the agent machine. If so, each time when you run the pipeline on this **self-hosted agent**, you can set the pipeline to directly access these binary files from the fixed directory on the agent machine, and do not need to download these files every time.

Due to at the end of the each job run there are some automatic post-tasks to clear the pipeline working directory, you need to store the binary files outside the pipeline working directory to avoid them are cleared.